# Show colored circles for product color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display color options circles on my product grid.

1. What's the propper way to do it? Is it right?
2. How to center them properly?
3. Is it possible to make them clickable so that when you click on the color, the image changes?

[Illustration of what I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/381W3.png)

Thanks in advance for your help. Here is my code:

```css
.prd-col-dot{
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  margin: 2px 2px 8px 2px;
}
.prd-col{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="prd-col">
  <span class="prd-col-dot" style="background: <?php echo $result['color1']; ?>;"></span>
  <span class="prd-col-dot" style="background: <?php echo $result['color2']; ?>;"></span>
  <span class="prd-col-dot" style="background: <?php echo $result['color3']; ?>;"></span>
  <span class="prd-col-dot" style="background: <?php echo $result['color4']; ?>;"></span>
  <span class="prd-col-dot" style="background: <?php echo $result['color5']; ?>;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this problem related to PHP, MySQL, or [tag:geometry]?

Comment: Hello @Nico Haase thank you for your contribution. Tags are changed.

Comment: To make them clickable I would say just add `onclick="JSfunction()/href location"` attribute to you `<span>` tag

Comment: Thank you @hugomztl. Do you know how to center the dots? Right now they are aligned to the left...

Comment: Why did you add a JS tag now? Your code does not contain any such code. Also, please focus on **one** question per post

Comment: how do you wanna center them? By which side, one by one, how many rows, horizontally or vertically? Please provide more details

Comment: @Ivan Kharkovsky I would like the dots as shown in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/381W3.png.

Comment: I've describe this one in the answer for question below

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also contain how coloring circles (which looks like a pure CSS problem to me) is related to Javascript, and your attempts to resolve the problem. Making something clickable to change classes is well documented in tons of tutorials, so it should not be too hard to apply any of them

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox model for centering it. As an example:

```
.prd-col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also for your container, you can use the same code with the additional rule:
`flex-direction: column;`

Answer (score 0):

To get a output like the image you provided,

1. you can use the proper styles like flex property in css(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

2. Using Flex property you can center the circles.
3. Yes, It is possible to make them clickable to change the image.

```css
    .image{
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .prodCol{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
     }
    .dot {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;
        padding: 8px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        margin: 10px; 
        
      }
            .dot:nth-child(1) {
              background: orange;
            }
            .dot:nth-child(2) {
              background: red;
            }
            .dot:nth-child(3) {
              background: lightBlue;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <img class="iamge" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg" id="myImage">
  <div class="prodCol">
    <div class="dot" id="1" onclick="changeImage(this.id);"></div>
    <div class="dot" id="2" onclick="changeImage(this.id);"></div>
    <div class="dot" id="3" onclick="changeImage(this.id);"></div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
  function changeImage(clicked_id) {
  
     const imgArr = [
     "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg",          "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/avenue-815297__340.jpg",        "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colombo-sri-lanka-december-05-2018-view-of-the-colombo-city-skyline-picture-id1181382649?k=20&m=1181382649&s=612x612&w=0&h=pkUSmxQ4G7vDFDYMZr9QEttKNYOKfuhzzvEIVoGRJPc="
     ];
  
     var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
     
     if(clicked_id == "1"){
        image.src = imgArr[0];
     }else if(clicked_id == "2"){
        image.src = imgArr[1]
     }else {
        image.src = imgArr[2];
     }
   }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is an example code. You can customize it to your one.